# Algorithm in pseudocode for finding the closest value that's not greater than a fixed value?

Tags: algorithm, fixed, blackjack

How can I write pseudocode for something when I set a fixed value, and the user inputs guesses as to what the value is but they winner is the value that is close to my fixed value without going over? Sort of like blackjack?

Not sure how to go about this.

For example: if my fixed value is 33.65 and the guesses are 32.90, 21.12, 33.68, 32.00 then the winner would be 32.90.

I'll be coding this in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the array in increasing order and then iterate through the array backwards. Return the first value that is less than or equal to the fixed value.

In python-esque pseudocode

```
fixed_value = 4
arr = [9, 4, 5, 6, 3, 7, 8, 1, 2]

sort(arr)
>>> arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

for value in arr:
    if value <= fixed_value:
        return value
>>> 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You could:

- create a List of guesses
- sort the guesses according to the absolute value of the difference from the target value
- the first element is then your winner

To sort the List, use `Collections.sort()` with a `Comparator` to based on the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting as others suggest is a way to get the answer, but it's a relatively expensive way if you don't otherwise need the guesses in sorted order.

In C-based pseudo-code:

```
float answer = 33.65;
float guess[4] = {32.90, 21.12, 33.68, 32.00};
float best_guess = -1.0; /* none! */
float smallest_difference = answer; /* start out large! */
int num_guesses = 4;

for (int i = 0; i < num_guesses; i++) {
    float difference = answer - guess;
    if (difference < 0) continue; /* on to the next guess */
    if (difference < smallest_difference) {
        best_guess = guess;
        smallest_difference = answer - guess);
    }
}

printf("The best guess was %f\n", best_guess);
```

Making this work in Java should be a trivial exercise.